# need to sort out strings from a text file, python

Tags: python

I've made a program that's looking through social security numbers and putting them into a textfile either as I wrote them into the program (if the number was valid). or with a comment like the number is too long if the number is too long.

Now i want to be able to "call for them" separatly but i have no idea how to separate the valid numbers from the invalid ones in my textfile.

```
def showALLnumbers():
    print ("all numbers:")
    textfile = open("textfile.txt", "r")
    data = textfile.read()
    print (data)
    textfile.close
```

This is how I call for them all but how do I get just the ones with comments like below, and how do I get the ones without these kind of comments?

```
if socialsecuritynumber.isdigit()== False:
    print (number, "\t", "not only digits")
    textfile.write("\n" + socialsecuritynumber + "\t" + "not only digits" )
    return False
```

Sorry for messy text but would appreciate help!

EDIT - this is how it looks in the text file

1. 1992051155700   too many digits
2. 9205115570
3. 92051155700
4. 199205115570    incorrect form
   thats how the textfile looks but without the 1, 2 ,3 ,4

Comment: Can you show what your file looks like?

Comment: Please update your question to include that :)

Comment: i think i managed to add it now ^^

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, you really should save your code in a better format -- [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is a great format, and Python has intuitive support for it. Being able to load and change things in Excel can be really important!

Regardless, let's work with what you've got right now. What we're going to do is run through each line of the file and check if there's a comment by splitting the line by a space character. CSV works essentially the same way, except it forces requirements on the way lines are split so that it's structured and you won't accidentally split something where you didn't mean to. Notice how if we split by space that if we maybe have an entry like "1234 5678", it won't parse correctly!

Onto the code. From your question, it sounds like you don't want to have any saved data structures, which may run into performance issues if your file gets *really* big -- I assume we're nowhere near that scale, so that's fine.

```
def showGoodNumbers():
    print ("all good numbers:")
    textfile = open("textfile.txt", "r")
    for line in textfile.readlines():
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        if len(split_line) == 1:
            print(split_line) # this will print as a tuple
    textfile.close

def showBadNumbers():
    print ("all bad numbers:")
    textfile = open("textfile.txt", "r")
    for line in textfile.readlines():
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        if len(split_line) > 1:
            print(split_line) # this will print as a tuple
    textfile.close
```

You could also combine them into one call to create two lists with getters:

```
good = []
bad = []

def getNumbers():
    textfile = open("textfile.txt", "r")
    for line in textfile.readlines():
        split_line = line.split(' ')
        if len(split_line) > 1:
            good.append(line)
        else:
            bad.append(line)
    textfile.close

def getBadNumbers():
    print("Getting bad numbers")
    print("\n".join(bad))

def getGoodNumbers():
    print("Getting good numbers")
    print("\n".join(good))
```

Comment: Ah okay gonna look inte that!

hm ye that very helpful actually!! as you said its messing abit when theres a space in the number but is there any way to get around that? i guess i could add another space and make it split in "  "(two spaces) rather then one?

Comment: Honestly, your best bet is to convert your format from a text file to CSV; you can split by any character you want, but that's getting into "hacky" territory, and it still has the same issues (what if one line doesn't have it? what if you have a typo?). Using CSV (or any other organized file format that Python can read) will help ensure that your data is always separable exactly how you wanted it to be!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly sure exactly what your question is. Do you mean that you have a pre-commented batch of social security numbers and you need to pick out the ones with comments? If so, something like this:

```
comment_list = []
normal_list = []
for line in file:
    if len(line) > 9:
        comment_list.append(line)
else:
    normal_list.append(line)
```

Comment: hm well my program is putting all the numbers i add to it into a textfile on my computer and either comments on it if its an unvalid number or just puts it in my textfile in an empty line.

What im trying to do is to separate the numbers without comments from the ones with comments even though they are in the same text document

Comment: The above program works if you have one number per line, like this: `859234123\n385869232 Comment Comment\n`. If not, then what structure do you have?